# What's the proper way to alter a form in the control panel? (Using an extension in EE3)

Tags: control-panel, add-on-development, extension, ee3

I have looked through the hooks and cannot figure out which hook could provide a way to alter a form in the control panel (e.g. the create/edit member form or publish/edit entry form). I don't want to use the CSS/JS hooks because that's altering it client-side.

Is there a way to either:

1. Grab the output prior to it being sent to the client
2. (even better) Get the objects used to create those forms and alter them?

I also want my extension to be able to be called on every control panel page.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a way to perform that kind of modification using a hook.

What you could do instead (if you need to alter all forms) is modify `_shared/form` View file (but then of couse you'll need to be sure to keep the changes when you update the system)

Comment: Yuri is almost certainly correct. This would require a modification of core code; Control Panel views don't go through a hook and get rendered by the templating engine, so there's no reasonable way to modify them on the fly like that, expect an accessory which would require browser side changes to the form.

Comment: In EE2, doesn't "channel_form_entry_form_absolute_start" allow this?

Comment: @DonRhummy That's for front-end entry form I believe. Besides, Don needs to modify at least several forms in CP, not just entry form